# How to prevent insertion of \parskip glue?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tex-core

The codes of the two `\vtop` in the example below look very similar.

Difference is:

- In case 1 you have `\hbox{ccc\hfill}`. Due to `\hrule` no `\baselineskip`-glue is inserted between `bbb` and `ccc`. TeX does not go into horizontal mode. No `\parskip`-glue is inserted between `bbb` and `ccc`. (No vertical glue at all is inserted between `bbb` and `ccc`.)
- In case 2 you have `ccc`. Due to `\hrule` no `\baselineskip`-glue is inserted between `bbb` and `ccc`. TeX does go into horizontal mode. `\parskip`-glue is inserted between `bbb` and `ccc`.

Now assume a situation where you don't know if TeX will go into horizontal mode after the `\hrule` but in any case you don't want `\parskip`-glue/any vertical glue after the `\hrule`. In any case you want the thing to look like in case 1.

Is there a method to cancel or prevent `\parskip` glue in case material following the `\hrule` switches to horizontal mode without knowing before if this switching will happen?

```
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=4cm

\baselineskip=2cm

\hbox to\hsize{%
\vtop{\hsize=.3\hsize
  \hbox{aaa}
  \hbox{bbb}
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax

  \hbox{ccc} %<- TeX stays in restricted vertical mode
  \par\hbox to\hsize{This is case 1\hfill}

}\hfill\vrule\hfill
\vtop{\hsize=.3\hsize
  \hbox{aaa}
  \hbox{bbb}
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax

  ccc %<- TeX switches to horizontal mode
  \par\hbox to\hsize{This is case 2\hfill}
}%
}
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

[image]

```
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=4cm

\baselineskip=2cm

\hbox to\hsize{%
\vtop{\hsize=.3\hsize
  \hbox{aaa}
  \hbox{bbb}
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax
  \everypar{\setbox0=\lastbox\endgraf\everypar{}\vskip-2\parskip}

  \hbox{ccc} %<- TeX stays in restricted vertical mode
  \par\hbox to\hsize{This is case 1\hfill}

}\hfill\vrule\hfill
\vtop{\hsize=.3\hsize
  \hbox{aaa}
  \hbox{bbb}
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax
  \everypar{\setbox0=\lastbox\endgraf\everypar{}\vskip-2\parskip}

  ccc %<- TeX switches to horizontal mode
  \par\hbox to\hsize{This is case 2\hfill}
}%
}
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an attempt at further developing [the answer of David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564398/118714) which aims at the hook `\everypar` whose tokens are delivered whenever TeX due to switching to horizontal mode has just delivered vertical `\parskip`-glue and started a horizontal list by inserting the `\hbox` of width `\parindent`.

As you focus on the "codes of the `\vtop`" and not on the `\vtop` itself I assume that the desired method is to work out also in (non-internal) vertical mode where probably some `\begingroup`..`\endgroup`-thingie might precede and more paragraphs might follow the `\hbox{ccc}`/`ccc`/`\noindent ccc`(?)-thingie.

Probably you can mess around with `\everypar`, `\everyhbox`, `\everyvbox`, `\everymath`, `\everydisplay` to make sure that not only the next paragraph but generally the next thing that is typeset will cancel the changes to `\everyar`.  **I have not yet thought about whether there are more obscure situations to consider in regard to "the next thing that is typeset".**

In the example below the token `\skiprestore` respective `\resetskiprestore` is prepended permanently to each of the above-mentioned hooks. Usually these macros are no-ops.

The macro `\makemydamnverticalgap` redefines

- `\resetskiprestore` to redefine `\skiprestore` and `\resetskiprestore` as no-ops.
- `\skiprestore` to apply the redefined `\resetskiprestore` and to do some negative vertical skipping for cancelling out vertical `\parskip`-glue, to do `\noindent` in case the `\hbox` inserted for starting the horizontal list had the width `0pt`.

I decided for prepending tokens to the hooks permanently because then redefining these tokens can be done in terms of `\global` which means that the desired changes will survive the wrapping into groups.

**I don't know about the best way of implementing such a thing in LaTeX 2ε where the kernel itself plays around with all these `\every...`-hooks.**

**Also in LaTeX there is, e.g., the package [**everyhook**](https://ctan.org/pkg/everyhook) which allows you to mess around with the `\every...`-hooks. Be aware that the current release (everyhook v1.2, dated 2014/11/26) has a bug which leads to amounts of consecutve hashes being halveed , e.g., `########` being halved to `####`, whenever e.g., `\PushPreHook`, `\PopPreHook`, `\PushPostHook`, `\PopPostHook` and the like is carried out.** *(I addressed the issue on the package's GitHub-repository some months ago.)*

```
\parindent=3ex
\parskip=.5cm

\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\newbox\mybox

\long\gdef\prependtohook#1#2{%
  #1=\expandafter{\romannumeral0\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\the#1}{ #2}}
}%
\prependtohook\everypar{\skiprestore}
\prependtohook\everyhbox{\resetskiprestore}
\prependtohook\everyvbox{\resetskiprestore}
\prependtohook\everymath{\resetskiprestore}
\prependtohook\everydisplay{\resetskiprestore}
% I am not sure whether \resetskiprestore should be done with other hooks also.

\newbox\mybox

\gdef\skiprestore{}%
\gdef\resetskiprestore{}%
\long\def\makemydamnverticalgap#1{%
  \endgraf
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax\nobreak
  \kern#1\nobreak
  \hrule height 0mm depth 0mm\relax
  \gdef\resetskiprestore{\gdef\skiprestore{}\gdef\resetskiprestore{}}%
  \gdef\skiprestore{%
    \resetskiprestore
    \setbox\mybox=\lastbox
    \vskip-2\parskip
    \endgraf\ifdim\wd\mybox>0pt \else\expandafter\noindent\fi
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}%


\noindent This is some paragraph.\xleaders\hbox{This is some paragraph.}\hfill This is some paragraph.
\begingroup
\makemydamnverticalgap{2cm}
\endgroup
\hbox{This does not switch to horizontal mode. There should be a vertical 2cm gap above this.}

This is another paragraph.

\noindent This is some paragraph.\xleaders\hbox{This is some paragraph.}\hfill This is some paragraph.
\begingroup
\makemydamnverticalgap{2cm}
\endgroup
\leavevmode This does switch to horizontal mode. There should be a vertical 2cm gap above this.

This is another paragraph.

\noindent This is some paragraph.\xleaders\hbox{This is some paragraph.}\hfill This is some paragraph.
\begingroup
\makemydamnverticalgap{2cm}
\endgroup
\noindent This does switch to horizontal mode. There should be a vertical 2cm gap above this.

This is another paragraph.

\xleaders\vbox{\hrule height 0pt width 0pt\par This is another paragraph.}\vfill\break

\parindent=1cm
\parskip=4cm
\baselineskip=2cm

\hbox to\hsize{%
  \vtop{\hsize=.25\hsize
    \hbox{aaa}
    \hbox{bbb}
    \makemydamnverticalgap{0cm}%

    \hbox{ccc} %<- TeX stays in restricted vertical mo\-de
    \par\vtop{\noindent This is case 1 - \TeX{} staying in restricted vertical mo\-de}
  }\hfill\vrule\hfill
  \vtop{\hsize=.25\hsize
    \hbox{aaa}
    \hbox{bbb}
    \makemydamnverticalgap{0cm}%

    ccc %<- TeX switches to horizontal mo\-de
    \par\vtop{\noindent This is case 2 - \TeX{} switching to horizontal mo\-de and inserting {\tt\string\par\-in\-dent}}
  }\hfill\vrule\hfill
  \vtop{\hsize=.25\hsize
    \hbox{aaa}
    \hbox{bbb}
    \makemydamnverticalgap{0cm}%

    \noindent ccc %<- TeX switches to horizontal mo\-de
    \par\vtop{\noindent This is case 3 - \TeX{} switching to horizontal mo\-de and not inserting {\tt\string\par\-in\-dent}}
  }
}

\bye
```

[image]

[image]